# Confusion related to time complexity of dynamic programming algorithm for knapsack problem

Tags: computability, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

I have this confusion related to the time complexity of the algorithm solving the knapsack problem using dynamic programming

[image]

I didn't get how the time complexity of the algorithm came out to be $O(nV^*)$

Answer (score 1):

Since computing each cell in the table is $O(1)$, the running time is just the size of the table. The first coordinate ranges from $1$ to $n$, and the second one from $0$ to the maximal value ever encountered (so it's really a dynamic table), which is $V^*$.

Comment: I have a confusion. We run the dynamic programming with two loops lets say i from 1 to n and another loop v from 0 to nvmax. As mentioned in the picture, they have $V* <= nv_{max}$. So the limit is already decided isn't it?

Comment: If you do it this way, the complexity is $O(n^2v_{\max})$.